# oemplus shortcut doesn't fire

Tags: winforms, c#-3.0

I am trying to fire menu shortcut by + button , so I set its shortcut to oemplus

but click the + button doesn't work, am I miss any thing

what's the equivalent to oemplus in the keyboard, and what's the equivalent to + in the toolstripmenueItem

Answer (score 0):

for + part I used

```
 zoomIn_act.ShortcutKeys =  Keys.Add;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Keys.Add`maps to the numpad "+". `Keys.Oemplus` should map to any use of the "+" sign on the rest of the keyboard. In actuality, in some keyboard layouts, it doesn't register properly and you have to detect the actual keys mapped to it. For example, in the Swiss (German) layout, you need to detect Shift+`Keys.D1`.